# Apple TV as a Gaming Console?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use the [Apple TV](http://www.apple.com/appletv/) as a gaming console - and if so, how, and where are games available for it listed?

Comment: Seems like a speculation question, which almost always means it's not a good fit for the site.  I personally think it could work, but I could go either way.  At any rate, you got an answer. =]

Comment: "What are the pros and cons of using it as a console?" still invites discussion, which is not what we want to see in a Q&A question. Could you rephrase it to **only** ask for an objective answer?

Comment: The Apple TV can be modded to run arbitrary code, including  (in theory) Linux-compatible games and emulators, but it's a serious pain in the rear.

Comment: +1 @SevenSidedDie: Thanks, guessing it's also voids the warranty, right?

Comment: @blunders Very much so. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An argument can be made that they already have a gaming console: the iOS platform.  Some games ([The Incident](http://bigbucketsoftware.com/theincident/) comes to mind) already support streaming the game through an AppleTV, while using the iOS device as a controller.  With iOS 5, there is supposedly built-in support for streaming almost anything through an Apple TV.  My biggest critique of iOS gaming on my iPhone is that my fingers get in the way, so we'll hopefully see more streaming-the-screen-through-a-TV.

Comment: +1 @splattered bits: Awesome, just the info I was looking for. Do you know if the streaming is local or via a network connection?

Comment: That I don't know.  I'm not an iOS developer, so not sure how it's accomplished.  If I was to wager a guess, I'd say it happens over the network.

Comment: Following the link you provided I found the support page, it appears that a connect may be made via bluetooth or WiFi, which would lead me to believe it's a local connection; though it's possible it's not, meaning that the connection is routed to the console, over the net, and back to the console. Again, thanks for sharing!

Comment: It's possible I'm wrong, but it appears that the gaming console is the iDevice (e.g. iPhone, iPad, iPad Touch) - not the Apple TV itself. That said, your answer has been a huge help, and unless an answer pops up showing how to use the Apple TV as a gaming console, I'll take your answer as the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2020 it's totally possible to use your Apple TV as a gaming console.

Apple introduced [Arcade](https://www.apple.com/apple-arcade/) which is a subscription service, that provides access to many games available on macOS, iOS/ipadOs and Apple TV (you can even transfer game progress between devices). It has much less games that you can find in Steam or in PS Store, but it's totally fine for casual family friendly gaming.

You can even use controllers with Apple TV now - [Connect a wireless game controller to your Apple device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210414).